# What are these "scroll page designs" called?

Tags: html, css

I have no idea what the proper name for them are, and i'm sure this has been asked before, because i've seen the question pop up here on SO. But since I can't remember what they are called, I can't search for it.

So this design: http://www.xipiter.com/

I don't want to ask how to do these designs, because it's already been answered. But what is this design style called? Where they make the layout fill up the starting resolution, and then the user has to scroll down to see the real site (if you know what I mean).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to know is what kind of page it is called, then here you go:

### Parallax Scrolling Pages

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/parallax-scrolling.html

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a single page website, more here http://onepagelove.com/